# Load a JSON file stored online

Tags: android, json

Is there an easy way to point the code below to a URL that has JSON data.  Before I had the following with my Json file in the Assets folder:

```
InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("data.json");
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
```

What is in that data.json file is now stored online.  If I get the string of that URL as String URL = "http...whatever....data.json" how do I initialize the InputStream in the first line of code?

Answer (score 0):

That code is specific to reading from files.  You will need to setup an AsyncTask and pull the data in a background thread.

This page explains the issues and provides good examples.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html

**Update 1:**

Here is code from a project that pulls the data and parses it and populates a java object:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.HttpStatus;
import org.apache.http.StatusLine;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import com.google.gson.Gson;

public class RestServices
{

   public static String getServerAddress()
   {
      return "http://192.168.96.179:8090/";
   }

   public static String getRestURI()
   {
      return "api/";
   }

   public static <T> T getExternalData(Class<T> clazz, String uri) throws IOException
   {
      String responseString = "";
      try
      {
         HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
         String address = getServerAddress() +  getRestURI() + uri;
         HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(address));
         StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
         if(statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
             ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
             response.getEntity().writeTo(out);
             out.close();
             responseString = out.toString();
         } else{
             response.getEntity().getContent().close();
             throw new IOException(statusLine.getReasonPhrase());
         }
      }
      catch (ClientProtocolException e)
      {

      }

      Gson gson = new Gson();
      T object = gson.fromJson(responseString, clazz);
      return object;
   }


}
```

And how I call it:

```
class SiteConfigTask extends AsyncTask<Void, SiteConfig, SiteConfig>
   {

      @Override
      protected SiteConfig doInBackground(Void... none) 
      {
         SiteConfig sc = null;
         try
         {
            sc = RestServices.getExternalData(SiteConfig.class, "siteconfig");
         } catch (IOException e)
         {
            Log.e(TAG,"Failed to fetch siteconfig", e);
         }
          return sc;
      }

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(SiteConfig result) 
      {
         super.onPostExecute(result);

         if ( result == null )
         {
            EventBus.getDefault().post(new ConfigurationFetchErrorEvent());
         }
         else
         {
            // Adds an additional empty stream if there are
            // and odd number of streams, the new stream will be disabled.
            if ( result.getStreamList().size() % 2 != 0)
            {
               Stream s = new Stream();
               s.setEnabled(false);
               result.getStreamList().add(s);
            }

            updateSiteConfig(result);
         }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could request the resource via `HttpURLConnection` like the code snippet below.

```
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/data.json");

        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        inputStream = connection.getInputStream();

        int size = inputStream.available();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
        inputStream.read(buffer);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.disconnect();
        }
        if (inputStream != null) {
            try {
                inputStream.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```